# SQL query - selecting rows that contain data in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables. e.g.:

```
table1:

|Alias1|Alias2       |Alias3|
---------------------
|qaz   | **abc**def  |wsx   |
|edc   |rfv          |tgb   |

table2:

|Alias1    |Alias2 |Alias3|
---------------------
|**abc**   | qwe   |rty   |
|zxc       |zxc    |vbn   |
```

I want to display only the rows from `table1` where the `alias1` in `table2` is contained in `Alias2` in `table1`?

Comment: That's great.  What have you tried?  This is not a hard SQL query.

Comment: very simple straight forward join ..so what is the issue

Comment: Just to clarify I think his use of the word "contain" implies he's looking for partial matches. So it would not just be an inner join on those 2 fields.

Comment: Well, the OP should be specific about what he wants. Contains in this context can be abiguous.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.Alias2=t2.alias1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 t1
  where exists (  select 1 from table2 t2  
                       where t2.Alias1 = t1.Alias2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *
  from table1
 where exists
 (select 'x'
          from table2
         where table1.alias2 like concat('%', table2.alias1, '%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope queries below will help

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
                        Alias1 VARCHAR(35),
                        Alias2 VARCHAR(35),
                        Alias3 VARCHAR(35)
                        )
Go

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
                        Alias1 VARCHAR(35),
                        Alias2 VARCHAR(35),
                        Alias3 VARCHAR(35)
                        )
GO
INSERT INTO #Table1(Alias1,Alias2,Alias3)
SELECT 'qaz','**abc**','wsx'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'edc','rfv','tgb'
GO
INSERT INTO #Table2(Alias1,Alias2,Alias3)
SELECT '**abc**','qwe','rty'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'zxc','zxxc','vbn'
GO
SELECT 
        t1.Alias1,
        t1.Alias2,
        t1.Alias3
FROM #Table1 t1
JOIN #Table2 t2
ON t1.Alias2 = t2.Alias1
GO
DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
```

Comment: His first row of table1, value for alias2, shows '**abc**def', not just '**abc**', so that query would not yield a match in his example. He is not looking for exact matches. Also it's the same query that Pieter B posted.